# How do I make it so that scrapy runs the spider and loops it when I change to another website(same website different search)

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

```py
import scrapy
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import numpy as np
from time import sleep
from random import randint

PATH = "/Users/miguelcorredor/Desktop/cnn/chromedriver" # where the driver is located driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

i = 0 #list number

words= ["RNA+Delivery+vehicles", "animal+models+for+rare+genetic+diseases", "invitro+models+for+rare+genetic+diseases","genes","muscle"]
link = 'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=animal+models+for+rare+genetic+diseases' #list of words pages = np.arange(1, 5, 1)

class umpSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pubmed"
    start_urls= ["https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=structural+Visualization+of+LNP"]
    page="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term="+ str(words[i])

    for page in pages:
        page="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term="+ str(words[i])
        driver.get(page)
        sleep(randint(2,10))
        i=i+1

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.css('div.docsum-content'):
            yield{
                'tittle': product.css('a.docsum-title::text').get(),
                'Author': product.css('span.docsum-authors.short-authors::text').get(),
                'year': product.css('span.docsum-journal-citation.short-journal-citation::text').get(),
            }
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

well I realized I was doing the loop wrong and instead I had to do it inside the def parse

```
def start_request(self):
    yield scrapy.Request('https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=structural+Visualization+of+LNP')

def parse(self, response):
    for product in response.css('div.docsum-content'):
        yield{
                'tittle': product.css('a.docsum-title::text').get(),
                'Author': product.css('span.docsum-authors.short-authors::text').get(),
                'year': product.css('span.docsum-journal-citation.short-journal-citation::text').get(),
                 } 
    for i in range(1,5):
        yield scrapy.Request(f'https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term={words[i]}', callback=self.parse)
```